# Perl program on Strawberry on Windows needs "use POSIX" in order to evaluate <$sock> and read a packet from the port

Tags: windows, perl, posix, handle

Perl program to read UDP packets & clean the data and transmit to another port.
Without `use POSIX;` in the program it cannot turn `<$sock>` into a packet of data.

```
`$sock` comes from:
```

```perl
    socket($sock, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, getprotobyname('udp'))
    bind($sock, $sockets[0])
```

with `use POSIX` data comes in correctly:

```
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,37Oms:?Oh0bHEEMb=j5A5AtL00N0,0*76" (AIS data)
without that, <$data> appears as "GLOB(0x1563bcda6e8)
```

PERldocs "strongly discourages" using "use POSIX;"
https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX

```perl
    my $data = <$sock>;
```

should give me data from the socket, without `use POSIX`; it hangs at this point.

Comment: Need a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It's only an unqualified `use POSIX;` that's poor style, because of how much stuff it'll import. Best practice is to just import the functions and constants you're actually using

Comment: Right after the docs discourage the use of `use POSIX` are two examples of what it encourages you to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you should add `use strict`, it would tell you *why* your program doesn't work without POSIX: `PF_INET` and `SOCK_DGRAM` are not defined. With strictness enabled you would get errors like

```
Bareword "PF_INET" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at...
Bareword "SOCK_DGRAM" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at...
```

Which you can then repair by adding

```
use POSIX qw(PF_INET SOCK_DGRAM);
```

or by adding

```
use POSIX ();
```

and referring to `POSIX::PF_INET` and `POSIX::SOCK_DGRAM`, as the documentation suggests.
It's only importing *everything* from POSIX that's an awful idea.

The problem is that if you don't import and *don't* use strict, you're passing the *strings* `"PF_INET"` and `"SOCK_DGRAM"` to `socket`, which get silently interpreted as completely the wrong thing (probably whatever socket type and protocol correspond to the number `0`). The socket creation probably fails entirely, but you're not checking `$!` for an error, so you never find out about it.

### However,

Using any of the stuff from `Socket` and `POSIX` is rather 1990s. It forces you to do an awful lot of error-prone manual work, and requires different invocations for IPv4 and IPv6. On perl 5.20+ you could instead

```
use IO::Socket::IP;
my $sock = IO::Socket::IP->new(Proto => 'udp', LocalPort => $port)
    or die "listening on udp/$port: $IO::Socket::errstr";
```

which replaces the calls to `sockaddr_in`, `getprotobyname`, `socket`, and `bind` with a single, much more readable, call. The socket you get from that works in all the same ways as the one you get from `socket`.

If for some reason your perl is more than 9 years old, you can use `IO::Socket::INET` instead of `IO::Socket::IP`. It works simiarly, except for the IPv6 support, and it's been in core since 2000.

If you're reading a tutorial or something that tells you to do things the 25-years-outdated way, you may want to throw it away.